Как остановить цикл при нажатии кнопки в Telegram боте в библиотеке pyTelegramBotAPI
У меня есть кнопка, отвечающая за начало цикла и за окончание. Цикл засыпает каждые 5 минут. Как сделать так, чтобы этот цикл завершался при нажатии на кнопку остановки, получается во время сна. Использую синхронного бота. Структура кнопок такая [ Начать цикл >> Остановить цикл].

Запихните цикл в отдельный поток как вариант

А как это можно реализовать? Какая библиотека?

threading ‍♀️

asyncio не подойдет?

А сколько у вас циклов, для каждого юзера свой или один?

У меня цикл один

Тогда проще объявить один тред до запуска цикла бота и уже из бота управлять состоянием потока‍♀️

Не понимаю вас.

Перед тем как запустить цикл бота, запускаем отдельный поток в котором крутится ваш цикл. Затем через полученные команды в обработчиках сообщений управляем состоянием цикла в потоке.

Пойду изучу ту библиотеку тогда. Спасибо вам. Как я понял asyncio нужно для более сложных и массовых задач, как выгрузка множества данных из бд.

Если будут вопросы - пишите.

"asyncio нужно для более сложных и массовых задач" multiprocessing, threading, asyncio для распараллеливания задач

Поставьте булево значение, которое можно будет менять через кнопку. А в цикле проверяйте, поднят ли "флажок".
Если нужно не дожидаться конца сна — сделайте цикл в цикле, который будет спать по секунде и проверять. Если ему ничего не помешало — начинаем главную итерацию заново

Проблема в том, что мой цикл засыпает и получается весь интерпретатор спит и не принимает другие функции

У меня цикл устроен так, что он выполняет некое действие делает проверку и если новых значений некого действия нет, то цикл впадает в сон. А когда пользователь хочет завершить этот цикл, то есть кнопкой. то ничего не происходит, так как интерпретатор спит

Возможно можно как-то по другому это реализовать, но я почитал про асинхронность в питон и понял что ее грубо говоря нет из-за GIL. Можно конечно несколько интерпретаторов запустить, но это как-то дыряво выглядит

И вот я не заметил вашу вторую строку ответа. Даже если я сделать интервалы на сон, то это мне ничего не даст т. к. пользователь не сможет нажать кнопку в тот промежуток времени, чтобы цикл завершился. Получается так, что во время итерации цикла по 1 секунде есть очень маленький промежуток времени, зависящий уже насколько быстро обработает процессор это действие и вот в этот промежуток времени пользователь не сможет нажать эту кнопку, то есть в этот тайминг попасть. Возможно я в чем-либо не прав. Можете скинуть пример кода?

Я могу вам скинуть отрывок этого кода
